# RStudio: move focus among the panels

Tags: rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

`RStudio` shortcuts exist for moving between `Source` and `Console` panes .. and *showing* the `Environment/History` and `Packages/File System` panes .. but not *moving* to them.

*Keyboard shortcuts*: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts

[image]

It is a very frequent operation to switch between panes - and it should be supported by keyboard shortcuts: is there a hidden set of shortcuts and/or a way to add custom shortcuts to RStudio for this?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Usually what I do is use `F6` to switch between the panel.